# CodeIgniter Update database with join and if statement php

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, if-statement, join

Im making a leave approval system there are two leave types annual and casual.

```
    public function approve($id, $leave_type, $leave_start, $leave_end) 
{   
    $this->db->set('status', 1);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('leave');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = leave.user_id');


    if($leave_type == "Annual")
    {
        $this->db->set('casual_left', '`casual_left`+10', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('users');         
    }       
    else{

        $this->db->set('annual_left', '`annual_left`+3', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('users');
    }

    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;     
}
```

Im not sure about the sequence of the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
    $this->db->set('status', 1);
    if($leave_type == "Annual")
    {
      $this->db->set('casual_left', '`casual_left`+10', FALSE);
    }       
    else{
      $this->db->set('annual_left', '`annual_left`+3', FALSE);
    }

   $this->db->where('leave.id',$id);
   $this->db->where('users.id',$id);
   $this->db->where('leave.user_id = users.id');
   $this->db->update('leave,users');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
$this->db->set('status', 1);
if($leave_type == "Annual")
    {
        $this->db->set('casual_left', '`casual_left`+10', FALSE);
     }       
    else{
         $this->db->set('annual_left', '`annual_left`+3', FALSE);
       }

$this->db->where('leave.id',$id);
$this->db->where('users.id',$id);
$this->db->update('leave JOIN users ON leave.user_id= users.id');
```

Comment: Now it says theres a sql syntax error. Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`id` SET `status` = 1, annual_left = `annual_left`+3 WHERE `leave`.`id` = '1' A' at line 1

UPDATE `leave JOIN users ON leave`.`user_id=` `users`.`id` SET `status` = 1, annual_left = `annual_left`+3 WHERE `leave`.`id` = '1' AND `users`.`id` = '1'